# malloc fails with memory corruption on one of two (nearly) identical functions

Tags: c, malloc

I have two identical functions for allocating a contiguous block of memory for a matrix, one being for an `int` the other for a `double`. See below:

```
double** alloc_2d_double(int rows, int cols) {
    double* data = (double*)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(double));
    double** array = (double**)malloc(rows * sizeof(double));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);
    }

    return(array);
}

int** alloc_2d_int(int rows, int cols) {
    int* data = (int*)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
    int** array = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            array[i] = &(data[cols * i]);
    }

    return(array);
}
```

The `double` function works just fine but the int function fails with `malloc()`: memory corruption. Why does the int function fail when the double doesn't?

This code is for an mpi program and the `double` function sees calls with parameters 25, 25 and 60, 60 and the `int` function sees calls with parameters 27, 22 and 100, 100.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've got a 64-bit machine, and `sizeof(double) == sizeof(double *)` so you get away with the mistake in the second `malloc()` in the first function, but `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)` so you don't get away with the mistake in the second `malloc()` in the second function.  (On a 32-bit machine, you'd be wasting space with the second `malloc()` in the first function, allocating twice as much space as needed.)

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) **No.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.                                               v----v`  wrong type.
`double** array = (double**)malloc(rows * sizeof(double));` is the wrong size calculation.

It allocates for `double` and not `double *`.  So if a `double` size is more or the same as a pointer, this is simply an over-allocation.

With `int** array = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int));` this could be under-allocating on a machine with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit pointers.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660718/malloc-fails-with-memory-corruption-on-one-of-two-identical-functions/49660835#comment86331265_49660718)

Better to allocate to the size of the de-referenced pointer than the type to avoid this common mistake.  Using `sizeof *pointer` idiom is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// int** array = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int));
//                   v-----------v   size of the de-referenced pointer               
int** array = malloc(sizeof *array * rows);
```

---

Minor points:

Casting the return value of `malloc()` is not needed in C.

Consider that `int * int * size_t` may `int` overflow when `size_t * int * int` does not. Begin the calculation with the widest type.  Recall the `sizeof` operator return type is `size_t`.

```
double** alloc_2d_double(int rows, int cols) {
  // double* data = (double*)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(double));
  double* data = malloc(sizeof *data * rows * cols);
```